# Google Sheets' macro for changing a cell background color depending on input text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to make a macro in Google sheet for the following case

In a worksheet column, *say column J*, The allowed text inputs are "A", "B" and "C".

As soon as I put `A`, `B` or `C` (in the `J`th column) the cell background color should change to "Green", "Yellow" & "Red" respectively.

How can I do that?

I don't know much about macros, I just got the task to do so.
Can I get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to change the background color of the edited cell, only when "A", "B" and "C" are inputted to the column "J".
- "Google sheet macro" in your title and tag is Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about these 2 sample scripts? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Sample script 1:

In this sample script, "OnEdit" event of the simple triggers is used.

#### Flow:

1. Check the range of edited cell. If the range is the column "J", the script is run.
2. Check the inputted value. If the inputted value is "A", "B" and "C", the background color is changed.

   - If the inputted value is NOT "A", "B" and "C", the value is removed.

#### Script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor, and save it. Then, please put the value to the column "J".

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 10) {
    var colors = {A: "green", B: "yellow", C: "red"};
    if (Object.keys(colors).indexOf(e.value) > -1) {
      e.range.setBackground(colors[e.value]);
    } else {
      e.range.setValue("");
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the script runs for all sheets in the Spreadsheet.

  - If you want to run the script for the specific sheets, please tell me.
- This sample script supposes the case that one value is put in one cell.

  - If you want to put several values to several rows on the column "J", please tell me.

### Sample script 2:

In this sample script, set both Data Validation and Conditional Format Rule to the column "J".

#### Flow:

1. Set Data Validation

   - By this, only values of "A", "B" and "C" can be put to the column "J".
2. Set Conditional Format Rule

   - By this, when a value of "A", "B" and "C" is put in a cell of the column "J", the background color is changed.

#### Script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor, and save it. Then, run `myFunction()` on the script editor. In this script, the condition works by running the script only once.

```
function myFunction() {
  var rangeA1Notation = "J:J"; // Column "J"
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);

  // Set Data Validation
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().withCriteria(SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_LIST, [["A", "B", "C"], false]).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);

  // Set Conditional Format Rule
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule().whenTextEqualTo("A").setBackground("green").setRanges([range]).build());
  rules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule().whenTextEqualTo("B").setBackground("yellow").setRanges([range]).build());
  rules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule().whenTextEqualTo("C").setBackground("red").setRanges([range]).build());
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [setBackground()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor)
- [Class DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)
- [Class ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder)

If these methods were not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Although I dont seem to get it to work. I have put the `OnEdit` function in the scripteditor and saved. Now how do I apply it for Column J?

Comment: @RC0993 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When you use the sample script 1, after copy and paste the following script to the script editor and save it, please put the value to the column "J". By this, the script is automatically run. You can see the official document at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/). By the way, please use the container-bound script of Spreadsheet.

Comment: @RC0993 As a sample for testing, how about this flow? 1. Create new Spreadsheet. 2. Open the script editor and copy and paste the sample script 1 and save it. 3. Back to the sheet and put "A" to the cell "J1". By this, the background color of cell is changed to "green".

Comment: I have realized that sample script works but not on merged rows in that column.

Comment: Hey Thanks that works : ) Merging was not the problem actually I had to delete the value "A" which was already there and then had to put it again

Comment: @RC0993 I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.